# How to use date condition in Symfony (doctrine + oracle)?

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

How to use date condition in Symfony (doctrine + oracle) ?

I have trying

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('la')
            ->select('la.id')
            ->andWhere("la.dateCreated >= TO_DATE(':a', 'yyyy-mm-dd')")
            ->setParameter('a', '2020-09-01')
            ->getQuery();
```

However is error: the query defines 0 parameters and you bound 1

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I don't think there should be quotes on ':a', I'd put :

```
TO_DATE(:a, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Beside, how about :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('la')
            ->select('la.id')
            ->andWhere("la.dateCreated >= :a)
            ->setParameter('a', '2020-09-01')
            ->getQuery();
```